# Javascript, combining multiple dictionaries into single dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that is generating a dictionary with multiple keys and one value for each key.

`{AdvanceAxes: "NaN", AnalSect: "Rigid_Conc", Angle: NaN, AutoSelect: "N.A.", CaseType: "Combination", …}`

I want to combine these dictionaries into a single dictionary. In one way append to the dictionary at each iteration
End result will be a dictionary of arrays with the same keys as the dictionaries coming out at each iteration.
Something like this:

`{AdvanceAxes: Array(9168), AnalSect: Array(9168), Angle: o(9168), AutoSelect: Array(9168), CaseType: Array(9168), …}`

I have failed so far. Would there be a way to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using reduce and for loop as shown in one of the previous examples. That did not quite work. I also tried push that did not quite work either

Comment: `const toDict = (values) => values.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.entries(curr).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: acc[k] ? [...acc[k], v] : [v] }), acc), {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` like this:

```js
let data = [
    {AdvanceAxes: "NaN", AnalSect: "Rigid_Conc", Angle: NaN, AutoSelect: "N.A.", CaseType: "Combination"},
    {AdvanceAxes: "NaN", AnalSect: "Rigid_Conc", Angle: NaN, AutoSelect: "N.A.", CaseType: "Combination"},
    {AdvanceAxes: "NaN", AnalSect: "Rigid_Conc", Angle: NaN, AutoSelect: "N.A.", CaseType: "Combination"},
];

// iterate data array and use empty object "a" as accumulator
let dict = data.reduce((a, e) => 
  // iterate each object entry as [key, value] and use "a" as accumulator
  Object.entries(e).reduce((a, t) => {
      // create an empty array on "a" for each key (if it does not exist yet)
      // then push current value to it
      (a[t[0]] = a[t[0]] || []).push(t[1]);
      return a;
  }, a), {});

console.log(dict);
```